# Upgrading from Rails 3.0.9 to Rails 3.1 errors from CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an application I am upgrading to 3.1 from Rails 3.0.9.  But, I am getting a syntax error or something.  It reads:

> > SyntaxError in BooksController#index
> >
> > c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
> >     c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:93: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
> >
> > Rails.root: c:/Users/Travis/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/clicknslide
> >
> > Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
> >
> > app/models/user.rb:11:in `admin?'
> >
> > app/models/ability.rb:8:in `initialize'

Any ideas?

*Note:*
All controllers worked fine in 3.0.9

Comment: This is not from CanCan it is from MySQL2 not being compatible.  It is version 0.2.6 and rails 3 needs a newer one...problem is they are not compiling for Windows.

Comment: Might be useful to know: cancan2 (still on beta) is working on rails 3.1 (get it from github)

Comment: @vincent jacquel...I the gem works fine.  I found out later for some reason it was the MySQL2 Gem (0.2.6 not compatible with 3.1) thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just upgrade to latest version of `mysql2` gem. In my case it is 0.3.7 now.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with CanCan.  It is most likely MySQL2 if using Windows...have fun trying to update.